# Simplifying multiple similar If statements (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

Im working on a code for an adobe acrobat form, I want to add the following code:

```
var total =6301
var warranty
if (0 < total && total <= 3300){warranty = 194.25}
else if (3300 < total && total <= 4000){warranty = 197.5}
else if (4000 < total && total <= 5000){warranty = 202.15}
else if (5000 < total && total <= 6000){warranty = 206.75}
else if (6000 < total && total <= 7000){warranty = 211.45}
else if (7000 < total && total <= 8000){warranty = 216.1}
else if (8000 < total && total <= 9000){warranty = 220.75}
else if (9000 < total && total <= 10000){warranty = 225.4}
else if (10000 < total && total <= 11000){warranty = 230.1}
else if (11000 < total && total <= 12000){warranty = 234.75}
else if (12000 < total && total <= 13000){warranty = 239.4}
else if (13000 < total && total <= 14000){warranty = 243.95}
else if (14000 < total && total <= 15000){warranty = 248.7}
else if (15000 < total && total <= 16000){warranty = 253.3}
else if (16000 < total && total <= 17000){warranty = 258}
else if (17000 < total && total <= 18000){warranty = 262.65}
else if (18000 < total && total <= 19000){warranty = 267.3}
else if (19000 < total && total <= 20000){warranty = 271.95}
else if (20000 < total && total <= 21000){warranty = 276.6}
else if (21000 < total && total <= 22000){warranty = 281.3}
else if (22000 < total && total <= 23000){warranty = 285.9}
else if (23000 < total && total <= 24000){warranty = 290.5}
else if (24000 < total && total <= 25000){warranty = 295.25}
else if (25000 < total && total <= 26000){warranty = 299.85}
else if (26000 < total && total <= 27000){warranty = 304.55}
else if (27000 < total && total <= 28000){warranty = 309.15}
else if (28000 < total && total <= 29000){warranty = 313.85}
else {warranty = 999999}
```

I want to have this be a lot less repetitive as I have a lot more conditions similar to the ones above.

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach features an array with value pairs which works for any values.

```js
const
    getValue = total => [
        [3300, 194.25], [4000, 197.5], [5000, 202.15], [6000, 206.75],
        [7000, 211.45], [8000, 216.1], [9000, 220.75], [10000, 225.4],
        [11000, 230.1], [12000, 234.75], [13000, 239.4], [14000, 243.95],
        [15000, 248.7], [16000, 253.3], [17000, 258], [18000, 262.65],
        [19000, 267.3], [20000, 271.95], [21000, 276.6], [22000, 281.3],
        [23000, 285.9], [24000, 290.5], [25000, 295.25], [26000, 299.85],
        [27000, 304.55], [28000, 309.15], [29000, 313.85], [Infinity, 999999]
    ].find(([t]) => total <= t)[1];


console.log([0, 1, 3300, 3500, 3999, 4000, 4001, 5000, 10000, 100000].map(getValue));
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you kindly!

Answer (score -1):

Use switch case instead which is ideal in terms of optimisation & performance. This way the code execution directly jumps into the corresponding condition rather than going through each if else if condition.

```
var total = 6301;
var warranty;

switch (true) {
   case (0 < total && total <= 3300): warranty = 194.25; break;
   case (3300 < total && total <= 4000): warranty = 194.25; break;
   ...
   default: warranty = 999999; break;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like this switch is making anything easier or better structured in this case.